# How to make use of a dynamic button

Tags: delphi

Changing properties on a component is in my Delphi vocabulary. I created a button by writing code and it appears on the Form as its Parent, but I do not know how to execute anything with it.

Comment: Simply assign an `OnClick` handler to it. You can do that in code

Answer (score 1):

Sample - create runtime TButton and set him event OnClick...

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

{ TForm1 }

TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
    FButton : TButton;
    procedure OnButtonClickTest(Sender: TObject);
public

end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FButton := TButton.Create(nil);
    FButton.Parent := self;
    FButton.Left := 10;
    FButton.Top := 10;
    FButton.Width := 75;
    FButton.Height := 25;
    FButton.Caption := 'Click';
    FButton.OnClick := OnButtonClickTest;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnButtonClickTest(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FButton.Caption := 'Test OK';
end;

end.
```

I create a dynamic button FButton. Place it on the main form (Parent: Self) and set the event handler to click on it (method: OnButtonClickTest). When you click on button, on her caption change text to "Test OK"

Comment: Give an overview in simple language too as to what you're doing in the program.

Comment: I create a dynamic button FButton. Place it on the main form (Parent: Self) and set the event handler to click on it (method: OnButtonClickTest). When you click on button, on her caption change text to "Test OK"

Comment: just add it to the question buddy.

Comment: Edit your answer and move this text from comment. Also novice might ask - how to make OnButtonClickTest...